# How to calculate the RANK from another column than the Window order?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

Is there a way to calculate the "Rank" from another column than the one specified in the ordering of the Window ?

For explaining more clearly what I want to do, I'll use the following example:

**Data example:**

```
|       Date       |    Amount    |    Product_ID    |
|------------------|--------------|------------------|
|    2016-01-10    |     7000     |         A        |
|    2016-02-01    |     1000     |         A        |
|    2016-01-08    |     10000    |         B        |
|    2016-02-10    |     2000     |         B        |
|    2016-03-05    |     3000     |         A        |
|    2016-04-01    |     10000    |         A        |
|    2016-03-20    |     4000     |         B        |
|    2016-05-01    |     8500     |         B        |
|    2016-05-15    |     2000     |         A        |
|------------------|--------------|------------------|
```

**Problem**

So on this example, I want, first to partition the Window by "Product_ID" and order it by "Date", but then the calculated rank should be on "Amount" column instead of the ordered column "Date":

```
|       Date       |    Amount    |    Product_ID    |    Rank    |
|------------------|--------------|------------------|------------|
|    2016-01-10    |     7000     |         A        |     1      |
|    2016-02-01    |     1000     |         A        |     1      |
|    2016-03-05    |     3000     |         A        |     2      |
|    2016-04-01    |     10000    |         A        |     4      |
|    2016-05-15    |     2000     |         A        |     2      |
|    2016-01-08    |     10000    |         B        |     1      |
|    2016-02-10    |     2000     |         B        |     1      |
|    2016-03-20    |     4000     |         B        |     2      |
|    2016-05-01    |     8500     |         B        |     3      |
|------------------|--------------|------------------|------------|
```

I want to order the Window by "Date" so that I only calculate the "Amount Rank" on the past dates.

**Explanation**

To explain it even more clearly, on the partition over Product_ID A:

1. First Window (when ordered by Date):

   ```
   |       Date       |    Amount    |    Product_ID    |    Rank    |
   |------------------|--------------|------------------|------------|
   |    2016-01-10    |     7000     |         A        |     1      |
   ```
2. Second Window: Here, as the Amount of the second line is 1000 inferior to 7000 (amount of the first line of the Window ordered by date), the "Rank" should be 1.

   ```
   |       Date       |    Amount    |    Product_ID    |    Rank    |
   |------------------|--------------|------------------|------------|
   |    2016-01-10    |     7000     |         A        |     1      |
   |    2016-02-01    |     1000     |         A        |     1      |
   ```
3. Third Window: With the same logic as above, we get "Rank" 2 as 3000 is ranked second in the subgroup [7000, 1000, 3000]

   ```
   |       Date       |    Amount    |    Product_ID    |    Rank    |
   |------------------|--------------|------------------|------------|
   |    2016-01-10    |     7000     |         A        |     1      |
   |    2016-02-01    |     1000     |         A        |     1      |
   |    2016-03-05    |     3000     |         A        |     2      |
   ```
4. Fourth Window: Same logic as above

   ```
   |       Date       |    Amount    |    Product_ID    |    Rank    |
   |------------------|--------------|------------------|------------|
   |    2016-01-10    |     7000     |         A        |     1      |
   |    2016-02-01    |     1000     |         A        |     1      |
   |    2016-03-05    |     3000     |         A        |     2      |
   |    2016-05-15    |     2000     |         A        |     2      |
   ```

And so forth.

**What I've tried**

I've tried the following code to obtain what I wanted, i.e. to partition by Product_ID, order the window by date and take the Rank:

```
    SELECT
          Date,
          Amount,
          Product_ID,
          RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Product_ID ORDER BY Date) AS Rank
    FROM Data
```

This code gives me the following results:

```
|       Date       |    Amount    |    Product_ID    |    Rank    |
|------------------|--------------|------------------|------------|
|    2016-01-10    |     7000     |         A        |     1      |
|    2016-02-01    |     1000     |         A        |     2      |
|    2016-03-05    |     3000     |         A        |     3      |
|    2016-04-01    |     10000    |         A        |     4      |
|    2016-05-15    |     2000     |         A        |     5      |
|    2016-01-08    |     10000    |         B        |     1      |
|    2016-02-10    |     2000     |         B        |     2      |
|    2016-03-20    |     4000     |         B        |     3      |
|    2016-05-01    |     8500     |         B        |     4      |
|------------------|--------------|------------------|------------|
```

I've tried the same on the order by Amount:

```
    SELECT
          Date,
          Amount,
          Product_ID,
          RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Product_ID ORDER BY Amount) AS Rank
    FROM Data
```

This new code gave me the following results:

```
|       Date       |    Amount    |    Product_ID    |    Rank    |
|------------------|--------------|------------------|------------|
|    2016-02-01    |     1000     |         A        |     1      |
|    2016-05-15    |     2000     |         A        |     2      |
|    2016-03-05    |     3000     |         A        |     3      |
|    2016-01-10    |     7000     |         A        |     4      |
|    2016-04-01    |     10000    |         A        |     5      |
|    2016-02-10    |     2000     |         B        |     1      |
|    2016-03-20    |     4000     |         B        |     2      |
|    2016-05-01    |     8500     |         B        |     3      |
|    2016-01-08    |     10000    |         B        |     4      |
|------------------|--------------|------------------|------------|
```

**Nota Benes**

N.B.1: I've tried to do it on Spark SQL so SQL is basic. Any answer with Scala or pySpark is acceptable too.

N.B.2: This is my first post on Stack Overflow

Thank you very much for your answers and your comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very interesting problem.  You seem to want a cumulative ranking of amount by date.

I cannot readily think of a way of doing this using window functions.  Here is a method with an explicit `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT d.Product_Id, d.Date, d.Amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN d2.Amount < d.Amount THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 1 as rank
FROM Data d JOIN
     Data d2
     ON d2.Product_Id = d.Product_Id AND
        d2.Date <= d.Date
GROUP BY d.Product_Id, d.Date, d.Amount;
```

Of course, the performance is not as good as a window functions approach would be.

One approach that would work in some databases is to accumulate the amounts into a string or array, and then use string/array manipulations to calculate the rank.  However, even that might be tricky.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @Gordon Linoff !
It indeed does the job perfectly. 
On my full data of around 15 Million lines, it is a bit expensive but by cutting the data into smaller chunks, I can hope to achieve it.